# How to remove URL parameter "feed20%URL" in WordPress?

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, url, rss

This is my very first post.
Though this first post is started with question thread, I'm facing a problem with my WordPress-based website with URL parameter "Feed%20URL" in the end of every my website content's URLs. The example is like this:

`http://www.seniberpikir.com/20-shortcuts-penting-untuk-wordpress/Feed%20URL`

The URL parameter is always showing whenever Googlebot crawled the original URL, and I have blocked that URL through Google Webmaster => Crawl => URL Parameters and added the parameter as Other and No URL. I have already disabled rss feed on my website, also I always removed the error URLs via Google Webmaster URL removal feature, but it continues appearing on URLs error page.

How else can I disable the parameter? It could drain my organic search visitors because it's showing 404 error whenever googlebot crawls them.
Thanks.

Comment: It's probably best to fix the problem in WordPress, rather than trying to use GWT.  Looking at the source of your page, it's coming from this: `<link rel="alternate" type="application/rss+xml" title="Blog Title" href="Feed URL"/>`.  If you can't wrk out where the value is set you might be able to remove it with a filter in your theme

Comment: For example, I've removed feed links like this before: `add_action('init', 'avp_remove_feed_hooks'); function avp_remove_feed_hooks() { remove_action( 'wp_head', 'feed_links', 2 ); remove_action( 'wp_head', 'feed_links_extra', 3 ); }`, but that might remove more than you'd like

Comment: I have removed the line on my header.php and let's see what happens after that. Thank you very much.

Comment: You're welcome.  Looking at the source of the page, it seems to have done the trick.  Hope that's the case.